# Can a new separate AWS VPC affect a network in any way?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, cidr

I created a new separate AWS VPC with a CIDR  "10.10.0.0/16".  Can this  network to be in  a conflict with one of the existing Versatile cloud networks, specifically 10.10.10.0/24 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what "Versatile cloud networks" is referring to specifically, but creating a new VPC (Virtual Private Cloud) in AWS will not have any affect on the existing VPCs in your AWS account. The only time overlapping CIDR block ranges in your VPCs would be a concern is if you want to connect the VPCs together using [VPC Peering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html).

If you think you may use VPC Peering later, you should take the effort now to ensure your CIDR block ranges do not overlap, because that can be a difficult problem to solve later.